# Automatic "Confirm Transaction" Metamask

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, metamask

I have a webapp and when I send a transaction I need to approve this tx by clicking "Accept" in Metamask. I would like to implement an automatic non-clickable confirmation. Is it possible? How?
(Security is not important in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not quite sure I understand the question but I will try my best to answer it...

If you are talking about the confirmation prompt that you get when transacting using Metamask then there is no way of getting rid of it as that is how Metamask is coded. That has to do with the Metamask application and not your dapp.

If you still want to implement an automatic non-clickable response for users who send ether/tokens via other ways that do not involve Metamask... then you'll have to make use of [events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#events). Events will automatically detect when a user sends funds and can give them the response you'll have coded. *The response will also appear to those who sent funds via Metamask.

**UPDATE** :
You cannot change metamask's behavior using code on a Dapp. Metamask is a third party in this case that has nothing to do with your dapp.

So...  Is it possible to avoid this clickable operation with events? No.

Comment: My question is related to the part of events. For example, in [pet-shop-tutorial](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop), when someone wants to adopt a pet, it is necessary to confirm that you want to send this tx through Metamask to finish the operation. Is it possible to avoid this clickable operation with events? @YulePale

Comment: @sapiensapiens I have updated the answer as per your comment

Comment: I think a dirty work-around, is avoid using Metamask and implement your own wallet, which can create new wallet address or import users' already-owned wallets with encrypted json/private key.

Comment: Is there any example of that? thanks @Richard Fu

Comment: Not sure if it's a good example or not, but we are also developing an [Unity wallet](https://github.com/Block42World/block42-wallet-unity) where Metamask doesn't supports, so we built one using [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum) library, which provides all needed functions such as create wallet, send transaction, calling smart contract etc. I guess there's also a lot [examples](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.UI.Wallet.Sample) in the language you preferred.